# image button location different in local machine and IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC 3 page there is one collaps button I used Following CSS

```
.imgAccordin
{
    margin: -9px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top : 12px;
}
```

It is working fine but when I shifted my project to IIS. Location of above button going somewhere else.

Any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: can you add image for what you refering, i.e. how it is and how it should be..

Comment: You need some designer to fix it :)